# Hide content changes in div inside Aria-live ( polite ) from Screen readers

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have a div inside a aria-live region that's only for sighted users. Changes to that div shouldn't be announced in screen readers. I have tried using

- aria-hidden
- role = presentation
- aria-live="off"

IE and Firefox still read the changes. Chrome works fine. Pointers to deal with this issue is appreciated.

Comment: question not properly asked, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit the question to provide information like relevant code-source and errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

First off, any content or functionality available for sighted users should be available as is or in an equivalent format for screen reader users as well.
Second, if for some reason you are hiding content from Screen readers then it should not be within a aria-live region. aria-live exposes dynamic content changes to Assistive technologies. 
Try removing aria-live=""(polite/off etc.) from the code and add aria-hidden="true"(the element and all of its descendants will be hidden to Assistive technologies).